# Puzzle for Applying the Definition to a t distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The coeffcient of variation (CV) for a sample of values $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ is defined by
$$ CV = S/ \bar{Y}.$$
Let $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$ be a random sample of size $10$ from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Find the distribution of $(10) \bar{Y}^2/S^2$. 
What I have so far $$(10) \bar{Y}^2/S^2 = \sqrt{10} \bar{Y}/S = \frac{\bar{Y}}{S/\sqrt{10}} $$
[image],

My approach is to let $Z = \sqrt(10) \bar{Y}/\sigma$, which follows standard normal
and $W =(10-1) s^2/\sigma^2$ which has a chi-squared distribution with 9 degrees of freedom.

Then $T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt(W/v)}$...after some calculation which gives me $T = \frac{\bar{Y}}{S/\sqrt{10}}$. By the definition above, since Z and W are independent by construction for T variable, T has a t distribution with 9 degrees of freedom.

Can anyone find faults in this approach?

Comment: That's the third time you have posted this question, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z= (root10)\bar{Y})/σ$ will follow Standard normal. Hence $Z^2$ is Chisquare with df 1. Again $T=(10-1)S^2/(σ^2)$ follows Chisquare with df 9. $((Z^2)/1)/(T/9)$ follows F with $df$ 1,9..
I hope u hve gt ur hint.

Comment: how do you know Z is standard normal?

Comment: if Y1,Y2,....,Yn follows N(mean 'm' and variance $(σ^2)$,it implies       Ybar follows Normal with mean 'm' but Variance $(σ^2)/n$..is it clear now?

Comment: why mean is m??

Comment: After rearranging the terms, I got  $$\frac{\bar{Y}}{\sqrt{S^2/10}} $$ My two concerns are (1)is $\bar{Y} $ standard normal. If so, why? If not, how can I apply the definition I listed above? (2) what is the distribution for $S^2$?

Comment: $((Z^2)/1)/(T/9)$ is equal to $(10) \bar{Y}^2/S^2$ (what you are looking for). I mean that is equal to the Concerned distribution which you asked to find out.   Look Carefully,and m is just an arbitrary choice.Follow What I defined and if there's a problem feel free.

Comment: isn't it standard normal always implies N(0,1)?

Comment: Based on what you said, I changed my post. Please take a look!

Comment: What u did is absolutely correct..May i know where are you having the problem in it now?

Comment: just want to make sure: is $Z = \sqrt(10) \bar{Y}/\sigma$ follow a standard normal distribution?

Comment: yeah dat does surely..you can have the results from the theory of sampling distributions